# Updating deeply nested documents in ravendb

Tags: ravendb

I am having following document structure and I need to insert values in nested documents.

```
 {
      "Level-1": {
        "Level-2": {
          "Level-3": {
            "aaa": "bbb"
            "Level-4": {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

how can I get keys every time at any level. There is a function for getting keys

```
 var workingDOc = session.Load<RavenJObject>("xyz/b");
```

`workingDoc.Keys` will give me all key for this document But how could I get Keys of second level.when I provide key for nested document . For example now I want all keys for "Level-1".Is there any way?  How can I check that the key is of nested document. please help .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajdeep, you can't partially load a document. You can certainly have multiple levels of nested objects withing one single document and depending on your data model this is probably a good idea, however, you will always need to load the document as a whole if you want to do modify it.